# Reverse order of RSS in zRSSfeed?

Tags: jquery, rss, reverse

Im using zRSSfeed and everything is great but I need to be able to reverse the order of the feed, does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Can you show us some sample markup produced by the feed ?

Answer (score 1):

The latest version allows you to sort by date or title in ascending or descending order.

http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed